# Installing SOAP for Python

Tags: python, soappy, pyxml

I am new to Python, trying to learn it by doing a tutorial based on "Dive into Python" book.
I am already in chapter about SOAP and I encountered some problems, when I tried to install all required libraries to use SOAP.
The tutorial says I need 3 libraries:

PyXML, fpconst, SOAPpy

I've installed fpconst succesfully.
However I can't install two others. I read on some forum that to install SOAPpy I need to have PyXML already installed, so maybe the problem is only in the first library.

I followed instructions in README, but I'm getting some error and I don't really know what is wrong and how can solve it. See screen for details. My version of Python is 2.7.2+ and I am trying to install PyXML version 0.8.4.

[image: Screenshot of error.]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDas5.png)

The errors states that such file or directory does not exist.
I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

PS: Ah! I forgot to mention that. I downloaded PyXML from this source :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxml/

And it it written here that it is out of date and one shouldn't use it. So what is an alternative to PyXML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu, why not just install these with your package manager?

```
sudo apt-get install python-lxml python-fpconst python-soappy
```

The package manager should be your preferred way to install any software in a Linux distro - it will make your life a lot easier, and ensure you keep things up-to-date and can easily uninstall them.

Failing that, you could also use [PyPi - the Python Package Index](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).

```
pip install lxml
pip install fpconst
pip install soappy
```

Comment: Thanks - that was helpful. I didn't think of 'apt-get' when I saw clear instructions on site to download the tar file and then run it with 'python setup.py install'.Also thanks for mentioning about PyPi - it can be helpful for me in future.

Comment: Package management is something a lot of people find unusual. As different distros do it differently, websites will almost always just offer your a source tarball, but you should always check your package manager first - big distros have packages for virtually everything.